# Python gets stuck at pipe.stdin.write(image.tostring())

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am reading each frame of video and adding time stamp to it as given below.

```
command = ['ffmpeg',
            '-y', # (optional) overwrite output file if it exists
            '-f', 'rawvideo', #Input is raw video
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', #Raw video format
            '-s', str(int(width)) + 'x' + str(int(height)), # size of one frame
            '-i', '-', # The input comes from a pipe
            '-an', # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
            '-vcodec', 'mpeg4',
            '-b:v', '10M', #Sets a maximum bit rate
            Output_name]
    #Open the pipe
    pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    print('Processing....')
    print(' ')
    #Reads through each frame, calculates the timestamp, places it on the frame and exports the frame to the output video.
    #import pdb
    #pdb.set_trace()
    while current_frame < total_frames:
        success, image = video.read()
        if success:
            elapsed_time = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
            current_frame = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
            timestamp = initial + dt.timedelta(microseconds = elapsed_time*1000)
            cv2.putText(image, 'Date: ' + str(timestamp)[0:10], (50,int(height-150)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)
            cv2.putText(image, 'Time: ' + str(timestamp)[11:-4], (50,int(height-100)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)
            pipe.stdin.write(image.tostring())
            print('frame number',current_frame)
        else:
            print('video reader fail')    
    video.release()
    pipe.stdin.close()
    pipe.stderr.close()
```

However, after around 18k frames, Python gets stuck at 'pipe.stdin.write(image.tostring())'. It does not produce any error, but simply hangs. How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you monitoring RAM useage?

Comment: No. How can I do that while running the process?

Comment: Which Operating system?

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Use `htop` or `top`.

Comment: Sounds like the stdin buffer is filling because ffmpeg is not consuming it.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf: Currently, Python is stuck at frame 17224.0 and the 'top' is showing as in the attached Figure.

Comment: @jordanm: So, how can I avoid that?

Comment: I don't see any attached figure.

Comment: I couldn't attach in the comments. Its attached to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved the puzzle:

**stderr** buffer is filled up and the process gets stuck.
I managed to reproduce the problem under Windows 10.

- FFmpeg writes statuses to `stderr` from time to time.
- You are using `stderr=sp.PIPE`, but not reading from `stderr`.
- After encoding many frames, the `stderr` buffer filled up, and the process gets stuck.

You may either remove `stderr=sp.PIPE`, or making sure to read the data from `stderr`.

Reading data from `stderr` may be preformed using a Thread:

```
# Read from pipe.stdrr for "draining the pipe"
def drain_stderr():
    while True:
        try:
            stderr_output = pipe.stderr.readline()
        except:
            pass
```

---

I created a "self contained" code sample that generates synthetic video file, and executes the code using the synthetic video as input.

Here is the testing code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import threading
import datetime as dt

# Generate synthetic video file - resolution 640x480, 30000 frames, 1 fps
# H.264 encoded video (for testing):
#########################################################################
input_name = 'test.mp4'
width, height = 640, 480
total_frames = 30000
sp.run('ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size={}x{}:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -t {} {}'.format(width, height, total_frames, input_name))
#########################################################################


# Read from pipe.stdrr for "draining the pipe"
def drain_stderr():
    while keep_drain_stderr:
        try:
            stderr_output = pipe.stderr.readline()
        except:
            pass


Output_name = 'out.mp4'

command = ['ffmpeg',
            '-y', # (optional) overwrite output file if it exists
            '-f', 'rawvideo', #Input is raw video
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', #Raw video format
            '-s', str(int(width)) + 'x' + str(int(height)), # size of one frame
            '-i', '-', # The input comes from a pipe
            '-an', # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
            '-vcodec', 'mpeg4',
            '-b:v', '10M', #Sets a maximum bit rate
            Output_name]

# Open the pipe
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

keep_drain_stderr = True
thread = threading.Thread(target=drain_stderr)
thread.start()


# Open video file for reading
video = cv2.VideoCapture(input_name)

print('Processing....')
print(' ')

#Reads through each frame, calculates the timestamp, places it on the frame and exports the frame to the output video.
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()
initial = dt.timedelta(microseconds=0*1000)
current_frame = 0
while current_frame < total_frames:
    success, image = video.read()
    if success:
        elapsed_time = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
        current_frame = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
        timestamp = initial + dt.timedelta(microseconds=elapsed_time*1000)
        cv2.putText(image, 'Date: ' + str(timestamp)[0:10], (50,int(height-150)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)
        cv2.putText(image, 'Time: ' + str(timestamp)[11:-4], (50,int(height-100)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)
        pipe.stdin.write(image.tostring())

        print('frame number', current_frame)
    else:
        print('video reader fail')

keep_drain_stderr = False
video.release()
pipe.stdin.close()
pipe.stderr.close()

#Wait 3 seconds before killing FFmpeg
try:
    pipe.wait(3)
except (sp.TimeoutExpired):
    pipe.kill()

thread.join()
```

Comment: Yep. That was right. I simply removed stderr from the sp.Popen and it worked. Thanks a lot.