# FFmpeg transcoding video H.264 -> AV1 leads to distorted image

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, transcoding

I'm reading video from stdin via pipe similar to this one [Python gets stuck at pipe.stdin.write(image.tostring())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606499/python-gets-stuck-at-pipe-stdin-writeimage-tostring)

FFmpeg is using *libsvtav1* codec with options according to [documentation](https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/master/Docs/Parameters.md)

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -i pipe:0 -s {frame_width}x{frame_height} -r {frame_rate} -c:a copy -c:v libsvtav1 -preset 6 -crf 30 -svtav1-params "color-format=1:film-grain-denoise=0:mbr=2M" {output_file}
```

Here's couple of details about used FFmpeg version as well as input video

```
ffmpeg version n5.1.3-14-ge5b5dd6653-20230621 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.196_227d99d)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-ffbuild-linux-gnu- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-openssl --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --enable-libxcb --enable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --disable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --disable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --disable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libdrm --enable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --disable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags=-pie --extra-libs='-ldl -lgomp' --extra-version=20230621
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 331776 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1280x720, 331776 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> av1 (libsvtav1))
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
Svt[info]: SVT [version]:   SVT-AV1 Encoder Lib v1.5.0-12-g0f8b3a81
Svt[info]: SVT [build]  :   GCC 13.1.0   64 bit
Svt[info]: LIB Build date: Jun 20 2023 23:48:14
Svt[info]: -------------------------------------------
```

The output video transcoded by SVT-AV1 codec is blemished as you can see on the images below. Normally I would say it could be caused by wrong pixel format, but input stream has yuv420 format what is the same as encoder's pixel format parameter *--color-format*.

Please share your experience or ideas how to get it transcoding correctly.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]